# Add attribute to Zend form file element

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

I am working with Zend Form, and i would like to add some attributes to a file element, this is my Zend element :

```
$cv = new Zend_Form_Element_File('cv');
 $cv->setDestination($config->path->cv);
 $cv->addValidator('Count', false, 1);
 $cv->addValidator('Size', false, 10240000);
 $cv->addValidator('Extension', false, 'doc,docx,jpg,pdf');
$cv->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper'));
$this->addElement($cv);
```

I have tried with `$cv->setAttrib('name','value');`  but it doesn't work too

Do you have any idea ? Thanks

Comment: You can't override the name attribute - the first argument you pass to the file element's constructor is the name (in your example `cv`). Was this the only thing you were trying to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had un bug in my Zend Library, thats why i couldn't add attribute to input file. 
Thanks